# How can I find the request.headers in a json-server request?

Tags: mocking, http-headers, json-server

I'm trying to make my mock API ([json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server)) respond in one way if the client sent an `AUTH_TOKEN` in the headers of his request, and in another way if he did not. This code is what I'm using, it is from the json-server docs.

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server')
const server = jsonServer.create()
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json')
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults()

server.use(middlewares)
server.use((req, res, next) => {
 if (isAuthorized(req)) { // add your authorization logic here
   next() // continue to JSON Server router
 } else {
   res.sendStatus(401)
 }
})
server.use(router)
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('JSON Server is running')
})
```

Of course this works, except the `isAuthorized(req)` function needs to check the request headers. My `isAuthorized` function looks as follows (pseudo).

```
const isAuthorized = (req) => {
  return req.getHeader('AUTH_TOKEN') ? true : false;
}
```

This does not work, since the `req` doesn't have a `getHeader` method, but my intentions are clear - I need to check for the token, if it exists return true, otherwise false.

How can I achieve this?

`req.headers` returns the following.

```
{
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  map: '[object Object]',
  'if-none-match': 'W/"a...........5r/3c"',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'user-agent': 'App/1 CFNetwork/887 Darwin/16.7.0',
  'accept-language': 'en-us',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  connection: 'keep-alive'
}
```

Which doesn't really have anything to do with the headers that I send in my actual request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underneath is uses expressjs.
Looking at their docs (https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) it seems as if you can use `req.get('Header name here')`.

Comment: That's it - much appreciated!